# LINQ query where record does not exist in related table, or does exist in related table with condition

Tags: linq-to-sql

What is the optimal way to perform the following query?

I have two tables with the following structure:

[image: DB Tables]

I want to find all "unowned" assets - where that means there is no AssetOwner record which has the AssetID and either no EndDate or an EndDate in the future.

I have made a first pass at this query:

```
return from a in db.Assets
       where !db.AssetOwners.Any(o => o.AssetID == a.ID 
                                      && (!o.EndDate.HasValue || o.EndDate > DateTime.Now))
       select a;
```

But given that I lack experience with this, I want to know whether this is the optimal way to perform this query (I don't even know what the options are).

Cheers,

Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty good so far. Try

```
return from a in db.Assets
       where !(a.AssetOwners.Any(o => o.EndDate.HasValue || o.EndDate > DateTime.Now))
       select a;
```

Comment: Thanks, Pleun. I believe I can see the advantage of your approach - certainly is cleaner. When I figure out how to run the SQL Profiler and view the SQL generated I'll be interested to see how the two differ - benchmarking didn't give noticable time difference, the query being fraction of a millisecond anyway :) Cheers.

Comment: I'd believe they end up with exactly the same SQL. You do not need a profiler, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/0b3c71ae-f706-4ef7-b3ed-4a9fe659449d/

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks, mate.  I was getting the craps with the profiler.